# Swift enum value is not returned

Tags: ios, swift, function, enums, return

This is the problem about the return of an enum value. In my codes, score.gameMe and score.gameOp are game scores.When the sum of two scores is 0 and the first server is .me, updateServer4Single return .me. I expected updateServer4Single returned .opponent when the sum of two scores became 1. However, it didn't work well. I want to know why the value is not returned.

This is the actual result.

0 : 0
curServer4Single: me
 0 % 2 = 0
me
0 : 0
curServer4Single: me
1 % 2 = 1
opponent  <-- This is what I expected!! 
1 : 0
 curServer4Single: me <-- Wrong result.

Codes are here.

```
enum OrderPlayer4Single: Int, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    var id: Self {
        return self
    }
    
    case me = 0
    case opponent = 1
}

struct PlayView: View {
      var body: some View {
         Button(action: {
             settings.curServer4Single = updateServer4Single()
             print("\(score.gameMe) : \(score.gameOp)")
             print("curServer4Single: \(settings.curServer4Single)")
         })
      }

      func updateServer4Single() -> OrderPlayer4Single {

         var orderServe:[OrderPlayer4Single]

         if settings.s_serveFirst == .me {
             orderServe = [.me, .opponent]
         } else {
             orderServe = [.opponent, .me]
         }

         print("\(score.gameMe + score.gameOp) % 2 = \((score.gameMe + score.gameOp) % 2)")

         print(orderServe[(score.gameMe + score.gameOp) % 2])

         return orderServe[(score.gameMe + score.gameOp) % 2]
     }
 }
```

I tried to use enum values as a return value.

I expected the enum value is returned well but it didn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't posted all of related code. So where exactly is your issue might be hard to tell. Regardless, the enumeration is not a problem. The following example uses similar pattern.

Try placing your code into structures a bit more and test your units. For instance I can build something like the following:

```
struct GameModel {
    
    let gameStarts: Player
    private let playerOrder: [Player]
    
    var gamesMeCount: Int
    var gamesOpponentCount: Int
    
    init(gameStarts: Player, gamesMeCount: Int = 0, gamesOpponentCount: Int = 0) {
        self.gameStarts = gameStarts
        self.gamesMeCount = gamesMeCount
        self.gamesOpponentCount = gamesOpponentCount
        
        playerOrder = {
            switch gameStarts {
            case .me: return [.me, .opponent]
            case .opponent: return [.opponent, .me]
            }
        }()
    }
    
    var playerTurn: Player {
        return playerOrder[(gamesMeCount + gamesOpponentCount)%2]
    }
    
}

enum Player {
    
    case me
    case opponent
    
}
```

And I can write tests for it like

```
import XCTest
@testable import PlayGameTest // Whatever is the name of your project

final class GameModelTests: XCTestCase {

    func testGameModel() {
        XCTAssertEqual(GameModel(gameStarts: .me, gamesMeCount: 0, gamesOpponentCount: 0).playerTurn, .me)
        XCTAssertEqual(GameModel(gameStarts: .opponent, gamesMeCount: 0, gamesOpponentCount: 0).playerTurn, .opponent)
        XCTAssertEqual(GameModel(gameStarts: .me, gamesMeCount: 1, gamesOpponentCount: 0).playerTurn, .opponent)
        XCTAssertEqual(GameModel(gameStarts: .opponent, gamesMeCount: 0, gamesOpponentCount: 1).playerTurn, .me)
        XCTAssertEqual(GameModel(gameStarts: .me, gamesMeCount: 7, gamesOpponentCount: 13).playerTurn, .me)
        XCTAssertEqual(GameModel(gameStarts: .opponent, gamesMeCount: 7, gamesOpponentCount: 13).playerTurn, .opponent)
        XCTAssertEqual(GameModel(gameStarts: .me, gamesMeCount: 72, gamesOpponentCount: 13).playerTurn, .opponent)
        XCTAssertEqual(GameModel(gameStarts: .opponent, gamesMeCount: 72, gamesOpponentCount: 13).playerTurn, .me)
    }

}
```

All of these pass.

Now I can start making some logic. For instance creating a view model

```
import SwiftUI

class PlayViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var gameModel: GameModel
    
    init(startingPlayer: Player) {
        gameModel = GameModel(gameStarts: startingPlayer)
    }
    
    func takeTurn() {
        var game = gameModel
        switch game.playerTurn {
        case .me: game.gamesMeCount += 1
        case .opponent: game.gamesOpponentCount += 1
        }
        gameModel = game
    }
    
}
```

and adding some new tests

```
final class PlayViewViewModelTests: XCTestCase {
    
    func testTakingTurns() {
        let model1 = PlayViewViewModel(startingPlayer: .me)
        XCTAssertEqual(model1.gameModel.playerTurn, .me)
        XCTAssertEqual(model1.gameModel.gamesMeCount, 0)
        XCTAssertEqual(model1.gameModel.gamesOpponentCount, 0)
        model1.takeTurn()
        XCTAssertEqual(model1.gameModel.playerTurn, .opponent)
        XCTAssertEqual(model1.gameModel.gamesMeCount, 1)
        XCTAssertEqual(model1.gameModel.gamesOpponentCount, 0)
        model1.takeTurn()
        XCTAssertEqual(model1.gameModel.playerTurn, .me)
        XCTAssertEqual(model1.gameModel.gamesMeCount, 1)
        XCTAssertEqual(model1.gameModel.gamesOpponentCount, 1)
        
        let model2 = PlayViewViewModel(startingPlayer: .opponent)
        XCTAssertEqual(model2.gameModel.playerTurn, .opponent)
        XCTAssertEqual(model2.gameModel.gamesMeCount, 0)
        XCTAssertEqual(model2.gameModel.gamesOpponentCount, 0)
        model2.takeTurn()
        XCTAssertEqual(model2.gameModel.playerTurn, .me)
        XCTAssertEqual(model2.gameModel.gamesMeCount, 0)
        XCTAssertEqual(model2.gameModel.gamesOpponentCount, 1)
        model2.takeTurn()
        XCTAssertEqual(model2.gameModel.playerTurn, .opponent)
        XCTAssertEqual(model2.gameModel.gamesMeCount, 1)
        XCTAssertEqual(model2.gameModel.gamesOpponentCount, 1)
    }
    
}
```

And using it in view

```
struct PlayView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: PlayViewViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 4) {
            Text(currentPlayerText())
            Button("Take turn", action: viewModel.takeTurn)
        }
        .padding()
    }
    
    private func currentPlayerText() -> String {
        switch viewModel.gameModel.playerTurn {
        case .me: return "My turn"
        case .opponent: return "Opponent turn"
        }
    }
}

struct PlayView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        VStack {
            PlayView(viewModel: .init(startingPlayer: .me))
            PlayView(viewModel: .init(startingPlayer: .opponent))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your great response. I moved. I tried many things because I am a swift newbie. After many trial-and-error, I solved it. The target variable settings.curServer4Single is @_State variable of a ObservableObject class. I changed @_State to @_AppStorage and it worked well. I'm studying the difference of @_State and @_AppStorage and the reason It solved.